# EditText into a alarm?

Tags: java, android

my first time posting a question on this website.
Im a new person that has been introduced to android app a couple of weeks ago. Im using Eclipse. Min SDK is 8.
Basically, im practising my android skills by creating a reminder app where the user can add a reminder and time, and once the time comes, there will be a pop up message on the home screen reminding the user about the reminder.

Ive set my layout in XML. But I'm not sure which is effiecent. I would like to make a button when if the user presses it, it will create a edittext and the user can enter the time (in HH:MM 24Hour format). And if the user presses the button twice, 2 edittexts will appear, thrice and 3 edittext will appear etc. I dont know if this is efficient. 
I also have another way of doing this and it consists of using the TimePicker. Basically the user press the 'Add Time' button, and a dialog box comes up with a timepicker widget but I was wondering whether it will work because what if the user wants to add another time to the same schedule? How will 1 timepicker be able to store 2 times?

My current XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
android:text="Add Reminder Time" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button3"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:text="Delete Reminder Time" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:text="Set Reminder Days" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
android:text="Reminder has been set to:" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help people.

Answer (score 0):

**TimePicker** should work. When you click on button you can pop **TimePicker** and once user select the time you can create an **EditText** dynamically and add result of the **TimePicker** to the **EditText**. When user click on it for second time you will add another EditText dynamically and do the same thing.

Both method works. The difference is that if you use **TimePicker** it would be easier for users to set time and easier for you to control it.

Comment: Oh okay. But what if the user presses the button twice and the android system overwrites the first time? How can I prevent this from happening? And also, can I put a textview instead of a edittext since there will also be an option where the user chooses which day to be reminded and the days that have been chosen by the user will be displayed in the textview besides the time chosen by the user.

Comment: If you create your EditText dynamically after they set the time, it won't happen. They will press button-> TimePicker will popup-> They will select-> you will create EditText and pass the value to the EditText. If you will get input from user, use EditText. Otherwise you don't need